# Derivative of complex matrix pseudo inverse with respect to real and imaginary components

Tags: matrices, cv.complex-variables, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, matrix-inverse

I have a complex non-square matrix $\mathbf{Y}\in\mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$ whose inverse I compute using the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse, $\mathbf{Z}=\mathbf{Y^+}$.

I am interested in evaluating the derivatives of the real and imaginary components of $\mathbf{Z}$ with respect to the real and imaginary components of $\mathbf{Y}$,

\begin{equation} \left[\begin{array}{c c }
\frac{\partial \Re({Z_{ij}})}{\partial \Re(Y_{st})} & \frac{\partial \Re({Z_{ij}})}{\partial \Im(Y_{st})} \\[0.25cm]
\frac{\partial \Im({Z_{ij}})}{\partial \Re(Y_{st})} & \frac{\partial \Im({Z_{ij}})}{\partial \Im(Y_{st})} 
\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}

From (Hjørungnes 2011) I am aware that the complex derivative of $\mathbf{Y^+}$ takes the form,
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dY_{st}} \mathbf{Y^+} = -\mathbf{Y^+} \left(\frac{d}{dY_{st}} \mathbf{Y}\right)\mathbf{Y^+} + \mathbf{Y^+}  \mathbf{Y^{+H}}  \left(\frac{d}{dY_{ij}} \mathbf{Y}\right)^\mathbf{H} (\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y^+}) +  (\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{Y^+}\mathbf{Y}) \left(\frac{d}{dY_{st}} \mathbf{Y}\right)^\mathbf{H}\mathbf{Y^{+H}}  \mathbf{Y^+}.
\end{equation}

My question is whether I can then apply the Cauchy-Reinmann equations to get the the derivatives with respect to the real and imagianry components?

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c c }
\Re\left(\frac{\partial{Z_{ij}}}{\partial {Y_{st}} }\right) & -\Im\left(\frac{\partial{Z_{ij}}}{\partial {Y_{st}} }\right) \\[0.25cm]
\Im\left(\frac{\partial{Z_{ij}}}{\partial {Y_{st}} }\right) & \Re\left(\frac{\partial{Z_{ij}}}{\partial {Y_{st}} }\right)
\end{array}\right ] = 
\left[\begin{array}{c c }
\frac{\partial \Re({Z_{ij}})}{\partial \Re(Y_{st})} & \frac{\partial \Re({Z_{ij}})}{\partial \Im(Y_{st})} \\[0.25cm]
\frac{\partial \Im({Z_{ij}})}{\partial \Re(Y_{st})} & \frac{\partial \Im({Z_{ij}})}{\partial \Im(Y_{st})} 
\end{array}\right ].
\end{equation}

I am aware that their application requires the function in question to be analytic, but i do not know if this satisfied in the case of a complex pseudo inverse... If not, how else may i go about evaluating these derivatives?

*Reference:
@book{Hjrungnes:2011:CMD:2011870,
 author = {Hjrungnes, Are},
 title = {Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives: With Applications in Signal Processing and Communications},
 year = {2011},
 isbn = {0521192641, 9780521192644},
 edition = {1st},
 publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
}*

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann requires that the function you are differentiating depends on $z=x+iy$ but not on the conjugate $z^\ast$; since the pseudo inverse corresponds to the limit $Y^+=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}(Y^\ast Y+\epsilon I)^{-1})Y^\ast$ involving the conjugate transpose $Y^\ast$ of $Y$, it would seem this requirement is violated.

Comment: If  $\mathbf{Y^+}$ is complex differentiable (which i am under the impression it is based on [Hjørungnes 2011] ), does this not mean by definition that the function is analytic? Or am i missing some subtlety...

Comment: As far as the function $\mathbf{Y^+}$ holomorphic and if in case the conjugate transpose $\mathbf{Y^*}$ of $\mathbf{Y}$ depends on Z, then their might be a possibility to calculate these derivatives.